# Tate's thesis: Trace function & different ideal of $\mathfrak{p}$-adic fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have started reading Tate's thesis. $k$ is a completion of an algebraic number field at a prime divisor $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ divide the rational prime $p$. I am unable to understand what the absolute different ideal of $k$ would be. Even before that, I don't understand what the trace function of k over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ would be. Any source and explicit examples would be of great help.

Comment: The different ideal appears in the functional equation of the Dedekind zeta function of a number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$. With the embeddings $\sigma_j : K \to \mathbb{C}$ see $\mathcal{O}_K$ as a lattice in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then the different is the dual lattice. Tate reformulated the Dedekind zeta function in adelic terms : with p-adic integrals, Fourier analysis, Schwartz functions and Poisson summation formula in the adele ring $\mathbb{A}_K$.

Comment: @reuns I understand the trace and different ideal of a number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$. Here, I am asking about the trace and different of $k/\mathbb{Q}_p$. To clarify, $k=K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: I see... And therefore I believe the different ideal would be $\{x\in K_{\mathfrak{p}} : Tr_{K_{\mathfrak{p}/Q_{p}}}(xy)\in Q_{p} \forall y\in K_{\mathfrak{p}}\}$.

Comment: If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, $\sigma \in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}), \sigma(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathfrak{p}$ then $\sigma$ is well-defined on $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^m$ as well as $\varprojlim_m \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}^m$ and $K_\mathfrak{p}$, thus $$Tr_{K_\mathfrak{p}/\mathbb{Q}_p}(\alpha)=\frac{1}{|D_\mathfrak{p}/I_\mathfrak{p}|}\sum_{\sigma \in D_\mathfrak{p}}\sigma(\alpha)= \sum_{\sigma \in D_\mathfrak{p}/I_\mathfrak{p}}\sigma(\alpha)=\sum_{l= 1}^{f_p} Frob_\mathfrak{p}^l(\alpha)$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, one should have in mind that for a finite-degree separable field extension $L/K$, the *trace* *pairing* $\langle x,y\rangle={\mathrm tr}^L_K xy$ is *non-degenerate*. Here the trace is Galois trace, which, notably, does not depend on the extension being Galois. Rather, ${\mathrm tr}x$ is the sum, in a Galois closure of $L$ over $K$, of all the conjugates of $x$... which, by Galois theory, lies in the ground field $K$, in fact.

Thus, for example, for a finite (unavoidably separable, because characteristic is $0$) extension $k/\mathbb Q_p$, trace is non-degenerate, and is "sum of conjugates". An often unasked question amounts to comparison of the "global trace" (of number field $K/\mathbb Q$) to the *local* traces $K_v/\mathbb Q_p$, where $v$ runs through places/primes of $K$ lying over $p$. A very useful point, too-often mistakenly suppressed because it's "not sufficiently elementary", is that $K\otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb Q_p\approx \bigoplus_{v/p} K_v$. In this context, it is not at all surprising that "the global trace is the sum of the local traces".

And, yes, for number field extensions $K/k$ and for local field extensions $K/k$, the *inverse* different is the fractional-ideal inverse of $\{x\in K: {\mathrm tr}x\mathfrak o_K\subset \mathfrak o_k\}$. In both cases, in addition to giving a duality by the trace pairing, there are strong connections to ramification.

(Also, I'd suggest that K. Iwasawa be mentioned in this context, since, after all, he gave an ICM talk in 1950 about doing this sort of thing. Not to mention Matchett's 1946 thesis under Artin about similar matters. "It was in the air.")